# Symfony new bundle unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony

I made a new bundle 
routing.yml:

```
_jihtest:
    pattern: /test
    defaults: { _controller: JihTest:Index:index }
```

create file directory /src/Jih/Test/... (eg. /src/Jih/Test/Recources/views/Index/index.html.twig)

i might an Indexcontroller:

```
class IndexController extends Controller{

    public function indexAction() {

        return $this->render('JihTest:Index:index.html.twig');

    }

}
```

but when go to the link it says: `Unable to find template "JihTest:Index:index.html.twig".`

what did i do wrong/forgot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Controller's name matches the name of a folder. In your case the folder name starts with lowercase character "i". Rename it to "Index".

Comment: That was a typo in my question

Comment: index.twig.html? Did you mean index.html.twig? :) Or is it another tipo?

Comment: pff yet another typo in my question, its fine in my ide though

Comment: do i need to configure the recources somewhere or should that work automatically?

Comment: It should work automatically. Well i found another typo. You wrote Recources, but it should be Resources folder name. Is this a typo in your question or you just named the folder wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The bundle name must end with `Bundle`, in your case:

```
_jihtest:
    pattern: /test
    defaults: { _controller: JihTestBundle:Index:index }
```

And

```
class IndexController extends Controller{

    public function indexAction() {

        return $this->render('JihTestBundle:Index:index.html.twig');

    }
}
```

Comment: Without the suffix you could have trouble in some automated tools, have a look at [this](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/bundles/best_practices.html)